# What per cent of the list price must be marked on the goods?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A merchant buys goods at $25$% off the list price. He desires to mark the goods so that he can give a discount of $20$% on the marked price and still clear a profit of $25$% on the selling price. What per cent of the list price must be marked on the goods?

Here is my solution:

Suppose the list price of the goods are $x$. So the cost price of the goods for the merchant becomes $0.75x$. Suppose the marked price is $y$. After a discount of $20$%, the selling price becomes $0.8y$.Since the profit is $25$% on the selling price, the profit becomes $0.2y$. Hence the cost price becomes $0.6y$.Equating both the cost prices, we get $y$=$1.25x$.
So we can say that $125$% of the list price must be marked on the goods.

Is this method and answer correct?

Comment: Yes the working seems correct if the $25\%$ profit is to be taken on the selling price.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the part 'profit of 25% on the selling price'. I arrived at the answer 125%. I checked online and many have answered 117%.

Comment: Yes they may have assumed $25\%$ profit on cost to the selling price. I felt the same way reading it but it can be argued given the wording is not very clear.